# Protractor typescript example error with tsc

Tags: typescript, protractor, tsc

I am trying to follow this example protractor script from here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/exampleTypescript

All of my npm installs go well, but when I get to the final:

```
npm run tsc
```

it fails for the reason in the screenshot below.
Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: To me it looks like you try to compare `Promise<void>` to a boolean. So you have somewhere an expect-statement, that doesn't contain a promise as value, but something else.
Can you add your exact test case to the question?

Comment: The code I used for this was taken right from this example (unchanged):  https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/exampleTypescript

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just delete your node_modules. Update the package.json dependencies to

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "protractor": "latest",
    "typescript": "2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2"
  }
```

2) `npm install`
3) `npm run tsc`